# MYSQLI INSERT MULTIPLE ROWS

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

this is my first post, and hopefully someone can help me with this problem I'm having.

I'm trying to take an item from a shopping cart table, and insert each row into the orders table. After they submit order, it should perform the action. Here is my code.

```
if(isset($_GET['submitOrder'])) {
   $timedate = $currentTime." at ".$currentDate;
   $order_number = rand(10,100);
   $cartOrder=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE members_id='".$members_id."'");
   $cartOrder_total = $cartOrder->num_rows;
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartOrder)) {
         $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO orders(order_number, members_id, product_id, quantity, date_submitted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
         $stmt->bind_param('siiis', $order_number, $members_id, $row['product_id'], $row['quantity'], $timedate);
         $stmt->execute(); 
         $stmt->close();
   }
   header('Location: cart.php#orderplaced');
}
```

My problem is that it's only inserting one entry into the orders table. Even if there are 4 items in the cart, it still only enters the one.

Please if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it! It only enters one row right now, and I'm not sure why.

Here are my tables:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`cart`(`
cart_id`int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
product_id`int(11) NOT NULL,`
members_id`int(11) NOT NULL,`
quantity`int(11) NOT NULL,`
date_added`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
date_submitted`varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cart_id`),
  KEY`cart_id`(`cart_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=153 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `members_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_submitted` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `order_number` (`order_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=422 ;`

Comment: You didn't mention your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post. But my problem is that even if i have 4 items in my cart, it only inserts one of them into the orders table.

Comment: how about removing `$stmt->close();` ?

Comment: what do you think that for loop is doing? seems pointless.

Comment: I tried to remove the $stmt-close(); part, and the loop doesn't seem to work. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: That for loop is of no use plus your order number will be the same for a member.

Comment: while is going through resultset. Dont know how many results does first query return but you dont need for loop here. For sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the database schema I can't be sure, but I suspect this is to do with you using the `for` loop inside the `while` loop. This will attempt to do the exact same `INSERT` with the exact same values `$cartOrder_total` times.

Simply remove the `for` loop, leaving you with:

```php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartOrder)) {
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO orders(order_number, members_id, product_id, quantity, date_submitted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
     $stmt->bind_param('siiis', $order_number, $members_id, $row['product_id'], $row['quantity'], $timedate);
     $stmt->execute(); 
     $stmt->close();        
}
```

Comment: It's still not working, but I'm updating my code to show the tables too.

Comment: are you sure first query returns more then 1 value? print  $cartOrder_total

Comment: It returns back 5, which is the total items in my cart.

Comment: order_number is UNIQUE,and you fill it with random value (which is the same,as you set it before while loop).

Comment: HOLY CRAP! Bojan, that was the problem! I can't believe I overlooked that. I feel so stupid now. THank you thank you thank you!!! I owe you, and I mean that. I'm a good designer, but still learning back end. Ever need anything, name it!

Comment: btw it is not that safe to use random for unique values. especially low range like 10 to 100. That being said, you can have at least 2 of the same values which would throw error in mysql (how often would that happen depend on your luck and number of results).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm gonna fix that right now! :)

Answer (score -1):

Which row you are seeing arrive through the     `INSERT`     is a clue to your iteration problem.  Alternatively, you could just add in an     `ECHO`      and just see what data you are moving.

If you see only the first row of data submitted, that is a clue you are not iterating through the outer loop's data.

If you see only the last row of data submitted, then that is a clue you have jumped to the last row of the outer data instead of iterating through each one.

Comment: It's only inserting the first item in the query. Then stopping.

Comment: Try using a fetch() instead of that fetch assoc().  Try this reference:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: Didn't help. Sadly :/

Comment: Without binding a result and fetching, I don't know what to suggest.  The pattern of: init, prepare, bind-param, execute, bind-result, and close, is pretty common.  Nest the execute and bind-result and result processing in a while.

Comment: put normal order_number, it is the same all the way through, anf it cant be as it is unique.